# Unknown column 'a.EntityVersion' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql

MySqlException: Unknown column 'a.EntityVersion' in 'field list'
MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ReceiveReplyAsyncAwaited(ValueTask<ArraySegment> task) in ServerSession.cs, line 962

```
MySqlException: Unknown column 'a.EntityVersion' in 'field list'
```

MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ReceiveReplyAsyncAwaited(ValueTask<ArraySegment> task) in ServerSession.cs
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
MySqlConnector.Core.ResultSet.ReadResultSetHeaderAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior) in ResultSet.cs
MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.ActivateResultSet(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in MySqlDataReader.cs
MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.CreateAsync(CommandListPosition commandListPosition, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, IDictionary<string, CachedProcedure> cachedProcedures, IMySqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in MySqlDataReader.cs
MySqlConnector.Core.CommandExecutor.ExecuteReaderAsync(IReadOnlyList commands, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, CommandBehavior behavior, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in CommandExecutor.cs
MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in MySqlCommand.cs
MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in MySqlCommand.cs
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SplitQueryingEnumerable+AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync<TState, TResult>(TState state, Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task> operation, Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task<ExecutionResult>> verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SplitQueryingEnumerable+AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync(IAsyncEnumerable asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync(IAsyncEnumerable asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Volo.Abp.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.EfCoreIdentityUserRepository.FindByNormalizedUserNameAsync(string normalizedUserName, bool includeDetails, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Castle.DynamicProxy.AsyncInterceptorBase.ProceedAsynchronous(IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo)
Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAbpMethodInvocationAdapterWithReturnValue.ProceedAsync()
Volo.Abp.Uow.UnitOfWorkInterceptor.InterceptAsync(IAbpMethodInvocation invocation)
Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAsyncAbpInterceptorAdapter.InterceptAsync(IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo, Func<IInvocation, IInvocationProceedInfo, Task> proceed)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager.FindByNameAsync(string userName)
Castle.DynamicProxy.AsyncInterceptorBase.ProceedAsynchronous(IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo)
Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAbpMethodInvocationAdapterWithReturnValue.ProceedAsync()
Volo.Abp.Uow.UnitOfWorkInterceptor.InterceptAsync(IAbpMethodInvocation invocation)
Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAsyncAbpInterceptorAdapter.InterceptAsync(IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo, Func<IInvocation, IInvocationProceedInfo, Task> proceed)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure)
Volo.Abp.Identity.AspNetCore.AbpSignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure)
Volo.Abp.Account.Web.Pages.Account.LoginModel.OnPostAsync(string action)
Volo.Abp.Account.Web.Pages.Account.OpenIddictSupportedLoginModel.OnPostAsync(string action)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory+GenericTaskHandlerMethod.Convert(object taskAsObject)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory+GenericTaskHandlerMethod.Execute(object receiver, object[] arguments)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeHandlerMethodAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeNextPageFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Rethrow(PageHandlerExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|26_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ExceptionContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Serilog.AbpSerilogMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass6_1+<b__1>d.MoveNext()
Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Auditing.AbpAuditingMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Auditing.AbpAuditingMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass6_1+<b__1>d.MoveNext()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Uow.AbpUnitOfWorkMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass6_1+<b__1>d.MoveNext()
Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.ExceptionHandling.AbpExceptionHandlingMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.ExceptionHandling.AbpExceptionHandlingMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass6_1+<b__1>d.MoveNext()
Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.MultiTenancy.MultiTenancyMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass6_1+<b__1>d.MoveNext()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ApplicationBuilderAbpOpenIddictMiddlewareExtension+<>c__DisplayClass0_0+<b__0>d.MoveNext()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Tracing.AbpCorrelationIdMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass6_1+<b__1>d.MoveNext()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.RequestLocalization.AbpRequestLocalizationMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass6_1+<b__1>d.MoveNext()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the table structure was generated using a version before abp 7.1.0, and there is no EntityVersion field.
Check whether the program connection database table contains the field EntityVersion.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I removed all the migrations and added initial migration. From the initial migration created, I have found that ABP 7.1 adds EntityVersion field with type Int to several tables - abptenants, abproles, abpusers and also abporganizationunits. I manually added the EntityVersion field with type Int and default value 0. I was able to login after that. There is mention of EntityVersion in ABP documentation in https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Entities#versioning-entities. Hope this helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).